# What is the most effective and efficient method of encoding text at the char level for input into a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning

What would be the most effective and efficient method of character level input into a Tensorflow model (yes, char level input is necessary).

For a given string "hello", 
and a char embedding "abcdefghijklmnop..." (~150 chars omitted for brevity), I have tried the following methods:

1) direct translation example:

```
[7,4,11,14] 
observation_space_shape = (max_length, char_embedding_length)
```

2) one hot encoding example:

```
[`[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1,0.0 ...], [...], ...] 

observation_space_shape = (max_length, char_embedding_length, 1)`
```

Which method would be best for achieving efficient and effective char level encoding on large textual inputs (with numerous characters), or is there a better alternative to the aforementioned solutions I have presented?

Answer (score 1):

Since character vocabulary (i.e., alphabet) is relatively small, one-hot encoding is a viable solution. For example, this is exactly what's done in [min-char-rnn](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086) by Andrew Karpathy (see [this post](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)).

Speaking of the large corpus applications, take a look at [CS 20SI](http://cs20si.stanford.edu/) example that analyzes and then generates Shakespeare-like text, character by character. [Here](https://github.com/maxim5/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/master/examples/11_char_rnn_gist.py) you can find a script: it encodes chars in one-hot and feeds to the RNN, and it works pretty well.

Character embeddings would have been more useful if there were semantic similarities between characters, like there are between words. But character 'a' is equally similar to 'b' and to 'z', so they aren't very useful for this task.

Comment: I feel the one hot encoding method will take an inordinate amount of memory and training time on larger character embeddings, do you feel the same? and if so, what would you suggest as a work around?

Comment: Do you mean that the alphabet is really large? Because even for word embeddings `d=100` is a default dimensionality (e.g., in gensim) and it's kind of applicable. I assumed that the alphabet size is of the same order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the char embedding isn't necessarily limited to alphabetical chars, the embedding may consist of chars such as numbers (0,1,2,3 etc.), symbols (@#$% etc.) and as such would need to be able to represent a large number of chars in a char embedding